# BitBucket merge git branch commits to master

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I found some similar posts but not as per the exact requirement, so posting the question. (git branch -f master branchToMoveMasterTo does not help)

I have a branch created from master long back. I need to merge all the changes from this branch named branch_mb to master branch.

Here is the structure of current branches:

```
master 
      |---> brahcn_is
      |---> branch_mb (30+ commits)
```

I need to merge all the changes from branch_mb, master should be exactly same as the branch_mb and commit history should be preserved.

Please suggest steps (merge, pull, fetch or any command is fine) that is reliable for production critical application.

Comment: *"git branch -f master branchToMoveMasterTo does not help"* ; ok, happens when you try that?  Also, you keep saying you want to *merge* to master, but then say *"master should be exactly same as the branch_mb"*; what does that mean? A merge means applying both lines of changes. Are you saying that `master` has no changes that aren't already in `master_mb` (so you'd be talking about a fast-forward rather than really a merge)?  Lastly, when you say *"commit history should not be preserved"*, what does that mean?

Comment: I dont seems to have any commits done to master after i created the branch_mb, i think merge should be same. I may be wrong with the terminology. I am looking for best practices. 
How do i create a new feature branch and once completed push it back to master etc.

Comment: If there are no commits to master since the branch was created, then the `merge` command would perform a `fast-forward` by default; but it's still a good idea to consider them different operations, because you *can* force a real merge (creating a new commit that links the two). But while that partially clarifies what you're trying to do, it's only the least important of the questions I asked. What do you mean about not preserving commit history, and what happens when you try the `branch -f` command?

Comment: I believe branch -f commands mentioned here ( git branch -f master branchToMoveMasterTo ) deletes the master branch and moves current branch as master. As i mentioned above already I "do not wish to delete the Master branch".  One option in BitBucket is to merge two branches, i am not sure if it will preserve all the commits or just merge all the final changes as a single commit.

Comment: The `branch -f` command moves the ref for `master` to `branchToMoveMasterTo`. If it's true that `master` has no commits after the branch's history, that's exactly the same as a fast forward.  Both a merge and a fast-forward preserve commit history. If you want a single commit, you have to rewrite history (squash, rebase, etc.) which has consequences when done to commits that have been pushed. Though it preserves history, a merge (rather than fast-forward) can be viewed as a single commit to master, e.g. with `git log --first-parent`

Comment: why is git so confusing :( (i wish it be like Microsoft VSS or visual basic)

Comment: I've only found git to be confusing when people try to think of it like VSS. It's a different tool and you have to learn its basics to understand it. For the added power and reliability, I'd take git over VSS any day personally; but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you just want to merge a feature branch to master. This is common practice in a typical git workflow.

This should do:

```
# Fetch everything:
git fetch --all

# switch to master
git checkout master

# merge
git merge origin/branch_mb

# push the master
git push
```

If there is no commit to master after branch_mb, then it will be a fast forward.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that :)

Comment: I get following error message when i try second command.
It says "following untracked working tree files would be overwritten... Aborting"

Comment: You should probably either do an add & commit for those untracked files before switching to a new working tree, or force overwrite. Another possibility is you can stash for now and decide later what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you want to overwrite `origin/master` with `branch_mb`?

Try this:

```
# This should Fail
git push origin branch_mb:master

# To truly overwrite master, force it
git push origin branch_mb:master --force
```

Comment: Thanks, will it preserve the commits history. Also please give complete list of commands (will it commit the changes to remote as well)

Comment: This will essentially, delete `origin/master`, and replace it with `origin/branch_mb` - History will be preserved for that branch, but master will be gone. If this is truly what you wish to do, I recommend doing the same thing here for master, but copying it to another branch name for the sake of a backup.